# Set Ack to look in handlebars files

Tags: vim, ack

I have Ack set up in Vim but at the moment it does not search in .handlebars files.

Does anyone know how I can add handlebars to the file list?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line to my ~/.ackrc tells ack to search in the files I needed:

```
--type-add=html=.html.erb,.html.haml,.handlebars
```

Answer (score 2):

We one command:

```
cat >> ~/.ackrc
--type-add
html=.html.erb,.html.haml,.handlebars,.hbs
```

also you should add a type

```
cat >> ~/.ackrc
--type-set
mustache=.html.erb,.html.haml,.handlebars,.hbs
```

and use like this

```
ack --type mustache 'search'
```

Comment: Version 2 of ack has changed it's sintax for ackrc like `--type-add=html:ext:hbs` to add `.hbs` extension to html types